# adb doesn't detect Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I made a .apk which I am trying to pass to an Android emulator using adb.
Unfortunately adb doesn t detect my emulator no matter what. I have read many other posts (that were multiple years old) on SO related to a similar issue, but none of the proposed answers worked for me. I ve tried to restart the adb server many times, without success:

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached

$ ./adb kill-server
$ ./adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

During this whole process the emulator was up and running.
What else can I try in order to put my .apk on my emulator?

I am using genymotion to emulate on mu machine which is running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in the in initial phase. please remove your emulator and install it one more time. emulator API 5.0 is better working. After installing emulator Invalidate and restart caches